# watchOS multiple toolbar items

Tags: swiftui, toolbar

my goal is to have 2 buttons as a toolbar item in my WatchOS app, but even if I group them in a toolbargroup or place multiple toolbarItems on their own, there is only one that is shown. Any idea what is wrong here ?

```swift
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem {
        Button("1") {
        }
    }
    ToolbarItem {
        Button("2") {
        }
    }
}
```

or

```swift
.toolbar {
    ToolbarGroup {
        Button("1") {
        }
        Button("2") {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found it. Placing them in a Stack (V or H) works

```swift
.toolbar {
    ToolbarGroup {
        VStack {
            Button("1") {
            }
            Button("2") {
            }
        } 
    }
}
```